# Python: creating a list named after a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a list named after a string. So for example I got the string `x = 'whatever'`. if I do

```
x = []
```

then the list will be named `x`, not `whatever`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How would you access the list once you created it? You wouldn't know how it's named. You should try to explain what you are actually trying to do instead. There's almost certainly a better solution.

Comment: Technically, the variable `x` will point to a list, the list is not named

Comment: This is really really bad practice.

Comment: Perhaps a `dict` of `lists`?  `{'whatever': []}`?

Comment: Your code should never rely on knowing an identifier name. In other words: if I ran a context-sensitive find/replace on an identifier, it shouldn't break anything.

Comment: Well, I create a list of filenames. I want to group them into lists based on their first 5 characters but I don't know what those first 5 characters are and I don't know how many different combinations will occur. What would be a better way to sort those into some kind of lists I can use?

Comment: @user5936897 please ask a new question for your actual problem. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in advance.

Comment: @user5936897 a dictionary of lists. `{"abcde": ["abcdefileone", "abcdefiletwo", ... ], "abcdf": ["abcdffileone", "abcdffiletwo", ... ], ... }`